# QMutex.unlock doesn't wake all blocked threads

Tags: multithreading, qt, pyqt, pyqt4, python-multithreading

I use Qt 4.8.4 and PyQt 4.10

Here is my test code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

class Thread1(QThread):
    def run(self):
        print('thread1 %d' % QThread.currentThreadId())
        mutex.lock()
        QThread.sleep(5)
        mutex.unlock()

class Thread2(QThread):
    def run(self):
        tid = QThread.currentThreadId()
        print('%d tid enters' % tid)
        mutex.lock()
        print(tid)

app = QApplication(sys.argv)

print('main thread %d' % QThread.currentThreadId())
mutex = QMutex()
t = Thread1()
t.start()

QThread.sleep(1)
threads = [Thread2() for i in range(10)]
for thread in threads:
    thread.start()

app.exec()
```

My problem is: when thread1 calls mutex.unlock(), only one blocked thread is waken.

Here is the output:

```
main thread 140017224202048
thread1 140016996386560
140016987993856 tid enters
140016979601152 tid enters
140016962815744 tid enters
140016971208448 tid enters
140016672044800 tid enters
140016646866688 tid enters
140016638473984 tid enters
140016954423040 tid enters
140016663652096 tid enters
140016655259392 tid enters
140016987993856
```

The document doesn't say anything about how to wake all blocked. How can I do that? THX

Answer (score 1):

A [mutex](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmutex.html#details) by definition limits (or protects) one piece of code so that only *one* thread can access it at a time. So you can't "wake" all threads if they all wait for one mutex, maybe you need many mutexes (one for each "resource") or depending or the design and constrains or your real project (since you posted the code from a "test application") maybe a [semaphore](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qsemaphore.html#details) will be better suited.

Answer (score 0):

Give a try to [QWaitCondition](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwaitcondition.html) and you could use condition.wakeAll() for your purpose.

Take a look at [wait condition examples](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/threads-waitconditions.html).

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if you still need this one. But i think you are missing the
mutex.unlock in your Thread2 class.

Your code should look like:

```
class Thread2(QThread):
    def run(self):
        tid = QThread.currentThreadId()
        print('%d tid enters' % tid)
        mutex.lock()
        print(tid)
        mutex.unlock() # line Missing
```